# AWS sdk get credentials using sso

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to use the AWS secrets manager, when I'm using regular credentials its works fine.
but I want to use SSO for it. when I don't have the `.aws/credentials` file and only `.aws/config` file.

In AWS documentation i saw this functions:

```
var params = {
  accessToken: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  accountId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  roleName: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
sso.getRoleCredentials(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

but I don't understand where I can get the access token, account id, and role name.
indeed I saw that in the `.aws/config` file there is an account id and role name, but I don't understand how can I get them into my code (maybe something like the function `SharedIniFileCredentials`) and also how can I get the access token?

Also,
I tried to add this env variable `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` but still I'm getting this error:

```
Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [credential-provider-sso](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso). The documentation gives a full explanation but a quick example:

```js
const { SecretsManager } = require('@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager');
const { fromSSO } = require('@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso');

const secretsManager = new SecretsManager({credentials: fromSSO()});

secretsManager.listSecrets({}, (err, data) => {
    console.error(err);
    console.info(data);
})
```

This will use the profile configured in the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable, or you can pass `{'profile': 'profilename'}` to the `fromSSO` function.